# Static files not loading [DJANGO]

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, static

My images aren't loading while using static files from Django and I can fix the problem. Basically I can load neither my favicon `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "images/FAVICON.png" %}"/>` and my other image `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "images/FAVICON.png" %}"/>`. I think that would be enough for you to help me solve this problem! If you need anything else just ask!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Antonio Gonçalves</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "images/FAVICON.png" %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="MENU">
      <div id="FOTO">
        <span class="ORANGE"></span>
        <span class="WHITE"></span>
        <span class="ME_CIRCLE"><img src="{% static "images/ME2.png" %}" type="images/png" alt="ME NOT LOADING"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

SETTINGS FILE

```
"""
Django settings for PORTFOLIO project.

Generated by 'Django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'Templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'w6gvds6*%jdyt1a(#go7i7=f#)(as#-q(1eso5@%0nx!5-agdc'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'PORTFOLIO.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'PORTFOLIO.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

URL FILE

```
"""PORTFOLIO URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from Portfolio import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='HOME' )
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

COSOLE OUTPUT

[image]

FILE LAYOUT

[image]

Comment: You don't seem to have a file named `FAVICON.png` under your `images` directory.

Comment: @Selcuk That That was an old image I will update it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweak your code with following factors.

1. `STATIC_URL` property in **settings.py**.

   update your static url to below property in `settings.py`

   `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
2. `{% load static %}` code to the **templates** file
3. and last but not least Your root **urls.py**

   Make sure to add `static` url into `urlpatterns` as below

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
   ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   ```

If this would not help you or have any further issues then put comment below.

Comment: So I did all of that but it says this in the console: `[10/Apr/2019 11:28:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 490
[10/Apr/2019 11:28:49] "GET /static/images/ME2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1767` but on the website it doesn't load the image neither the favicon. I will add my URL file to the question!

Comment: Can you please tell me why do we do the 3rd point in your explanation? Is there any way to run and load the static image without including this static part to urlpatterns?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration :

```
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),

    ]
    print (STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

If it still doesn't work install django again and do the above.

Answer (score 0):

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
]
Try this.
For further reference visit: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31978392)